# Can't reproduce phpbrowser error on real browser

Tags: php, phalcon, codeception

I'm running into some trouble writing a simple test using codeception.

It's a simple procedure to upload a excel file and check if the data on the excel file is available on the database after uploade. My test code:

```
public function do_carga_vendedores(BTester $I)
    {
        $I->amOnPage('/admin/carga/vendedores');
        $I->attachFile('templateupload', 'carga_vendedores.xlsx');
        $I->click('Enviar');
        $I->see('Cadastro feito com sucesso!');
        $I->seeInDatabase('usuario', [
                'cpf' => '332.895.032-08',
                'nome' => 'Test1'
            ]);

        $I->seeInDatabase('usuario', [
                'cpf' => '776.676.558-63',
                'nome' => 'Test2'
            ]);
    }
}
```

Generates:

```
Step  I see "Cadastro feito com sucesso!"
Fail  Failed asserting that   /admin/carga/doRealizarCargaVendedor
```

When I check the output file it shows:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getType() on a non-object in /var/www/apps/shared/models/BaseModel.php on line 82
```

Line 82 code:

```
switch ($message->getType()) {
```

I've done a var_dump on the `$message` variable and the result is:

```
object(Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Message)[148]
  protected '_type' => string 'PresenceOf' (length=10)
  protected '_message' => string 'nome is required' (length=16)
  protected '_field' => string 'nome' (length=4)
  protected '_model' => null
```

The whole code for BaseModel.php can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/MEY1wu1N)

But if I upload the file using chrome, the issue isn't reproducible.
I don't know if this is as phpbrowser problem or if there is a defect on my code.

OBS: Framework: Phalcon 2.0.5 / Codeception 2.1.1

Comment: You need to provide more code, for example, whats on line 82 of BaseModel.php?

Comment: Hi @SolracRagnarockradio, I added more information, thanks !